# Trec_eval make error using cygwin

Tags: c++, gcc, cygwin, information-retrieval

I'm using trec_eval.9.0 and try to run `make` command in it using **cygwin**:

```
Arezo@DESKTOP-JNNKBAS /cygdrive/d/Trec_eval/trec_eval.9.0 
 $ make
```

but the following error happened:

```
 In file included from sysfunc.h:21:0,
 from m_ndcg_cut.c:8:
 m_ndcg_cut.c:12:8: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘/’ token
 double log2(double x);
 ^
 In file included from sysfunc.h:21:0,
 from m_Rndcg.c:9:
 m_Rndcg.c:13:8: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘/’ token
 double log2(double x);
 ^
 In file included from sysfunc.h:21:0,
 from m_ndcg_rel.c:9:
 m_ndcg_rel.c:13:8: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘/’ token
 double log2(double x);
 ^
 In file included from sysfunc.h:21:0,
 from m_binG.c:9:
 m_binG.c:13:8: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘/’ token
 double log2(double x);
 ^
 In file included from sysfunc.h:21:0,
 from m_G.c:9:
 m_G.c:13:8: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘/’ token
 double log2(double x);
 ^
 Makefile:54: recipe for target 'trec_eval' failed
 make: *** [trec_eval] Error 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding

```
#undef log2
```

after `#include` section in `sysfunc.h`

That helped me to compile this tool.